# Locale inheritance after interpretation

Tags: locale, isabelle, interpretation

I am trying to understand how "inheritance" work at locale/interpretation level. I have an abstract locale (locA), with a method (g) defined within it. I have a concrete locale (locB), which is an instance/model of the abstract one. Is there a way to use the `g` method in such a way that I don't get a "type unification" error?

Below is a toy example of what I am trying to achieve

```
theory InstOverwrite

imports Main
begin

locale locA = 
  fixes f :: "'a ⇒ 'b"
begin

definition g :: "'a set ⇒ 'b set" where 
  "g X = f`X"
end

locale locB = 
  fixes fb :: "nat ⇒ nat"
  assumes fb_def: "fb n = n*2"
begin

interpretation locA
  apply unfold_locales
  done
end

context locB
begin
definition fx :: "nat set ⇒ nat set" where
  "fx X = {n+1 | n::nat. n ∈ locA.g X}"
end

end
```

Unsurprisingly, I get the following error:

```
Type unification failed: Clash of types "_ set" and "_ ⇒ _"

Type error in application: incompatible operand type

Operator:  locA.g :: (??'a ⇒ ??'b) ⇒ ??'a set ⇒ ??'b set
Operand:   X :: nat set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quick fix

Within your code, you have not actually connected the two locales.

`locA.g` exists “outside” the locale context in the sense that it must be supplied an `f :: "'a ⇒ 'b"` in order to be used. This is what Isabelle tries to express by stressing `Operator:  locA.g :: (??'a ⇒ ??'b) ⇒ ??'a set ⇒ ??'b set`. So, in order to make the type checker happy here, you would need to explicitly say that `fb` should serve as `f` *in the function application*.

```
definition fx :: "nat set ⇒ nat set" where
  "fx X = {n+1 | n::nat. n ∈ locA.g fb X}"
```

(The only difference is writing `locA.g fb X` instead of `locA.g X`.)

### Providing parameters to `interpretation`

From your description of the problem, I gather that you hoped `interpretation locA` would have taken care of establishing this connection. This is not the case.

To establish the instantiation that `f := fb`, you would need to supply parameters to the interpretation. The following would work:

```
interpretation locA fb .

definition fx :: "nat set ⇒ nat set" where
  "fx X = {n+1 | n::nat. n ∈ g X}"
```

(Note that it's now `g X` instead of `locA.g fb X`!)

### Maybe rather `sublocale`?

I conveniently dropped the end/begin context from the example script. The reason being that the context jumps would kill the interpretation. If you want the connection to persist across contexts, the `sublocale` keyword is more appropriate:

```
sublocale "locA" fb .
end (* of locale context locB *)

(* somewhere else we may add to the locale again: *)

definition (in locB) fy :: "nat set ⇒ nat set" where
  "fy X = {n+1 | n::nat. n ∈ g X}"
```

### Further notes on locale inheritance

Depending on what you're actually wanting to do, an even more different formulation might make sense. I assume that the listing is just the way it is to have some minimal example.

For people bumping into this question, I want to note that the locale inheritance situation here might be expressed more conveniently by one of the two following approaches:

#### A) Make `locB` extend `locA`:

The following will use the same `f` for both locales directly and just add the defining assumption:

```
locale locB = 
  locA f for f :: "nat ⇒ nat" +
  assumes f_def: "f n = n*2"
```

#### B) Make `locB` instantiate parameters for `locA`

```
definition fb :: "nat ⇒ nat" where "fb n ≡ n * 2"

locale locB = 
  locA fb
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you - yes, indeed I hoped that interpretation does more magic :D I'll have to figure out which one of your non-quick fixes will apply to my crazy implementation. Thank you for the suggestions, I can now explore a bit more. Much appreciated!  @ben-keks

Comment: One more question: what would be the difference / advantage of using A (extend a locale) vs B (specify a locale)? 

My real locA (that abstract locale) ends up having a decently large number of parameters (there are 2 different Boolean algebras involved in this). What would be some design criteria to follow when designing this mathematical structure that needs to be instantiated down the road?

Comment: If it's really just about instantiating parameters to a locale, I would always prefer B as cleaner. It also makes it easier to say use `fun`, `inductive` and the like to define `f`.
A might give you some more notational freedom if you have mutual dependencies between the objects that you want to make more concrete and the remaining locale parameters—but this might be more harmful than helpful. (I mostly added A to illustrate how assumptions would be added in general.)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Let me sleep on this one and refine some of my locales a bit more. I am sure I'll have more questions. Thank you so much so far!

Comment: @AliciaM. If it works, please also consider to *accept* the answer here! :)

Comment: I thought I had - it does answer my initial question, for sure.